# Вопрос о срезах в Python

Tags: python, срез

Почему вывод кода:

```
letter = '1234567890'
letter[::-1]
```

Такой же как и вывод этого кода:

```
letter = '1234567890'
letter[-1::-1]
```

И отличается от вывода этого кода:

```
letter = '1234567890'
letter[0::-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Объясню синтаксис срезов: `list1[start:end:step]`,
где

`start` - позиция, с которой начинать "читать"

`end` - позиция, перед которой закончить "читать"

`step` - на сколько символов сдвигать позицию "чтения"

То есть прочитать запись вида `list1[start:end:step]` можно так: "прочитать каждый `step` элемент `list1`, от `start` до `end`".

Значения по умолчанию следующие:

1. `step=1`
2. Если `step>0`:

   - `start` =0
   - `end` = len(list1)+1
3. Если `step<0` :

   - `start` = -1
   - `end` = как-бы `-1`, но при записи вида `list1[start:-1:-1]` мы получим пустой список

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103938/discussion-on-answer-by-n1tr0xs-----python).

Answer (score 2):

ровно потому, почему это `[1::1]` равносильно с этим `[1::]`.

а вообще в первом случае вы указываете **шаг** `-1`, как бы начиная с конца, во втором, указывая `-1` как **старт** ситуация не меняется, но когда вы указываете **старт** как `0`, идя при этом с конца, единственный элемент который будет затронут - это первый, с которого вы и пошли..

Comment: Пока, я утверждаю что нельзя вписать свои три аргумента срезу что бы он включал все елементы родительского списка в обратном порядке, а следственно я не понимаю какие аргументы ВООБЩЕ может подставить Python